# Is it possible to use the Drupal api to get a list of users?

Tags: php, drupal

I would like to get a list of all the users who have been assigned a certain role.  I could write my own SQL but I would like to use the api as much as possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are generally no Drupal API functions for this sort of task (pulling up entities that match certain criteria). It tends to focus on single-entity CRUD functions in the API; everything else is up to a developer's own SQL skills.

The Views module allows you to build lists of users filtered by role, permission, etc -- but it could easily be overkill.

Comment: I would make my own answer but I feel I should just expand on this.  There is no function which allows you to list users and filter by role within Drupal (core at least).  You can write your own function or like eaton said, use views to create a list of users.

Comment: you __really__ should use views. it is the solution you're looking for.

Answer (score 9):

You can use entity_load to get array of users. Here is the sample that will create list of all emails for admin users (used to send notification)

```
<?php
$users = entity_load('user');
$emails = '';
foreach($users as $user) {
  if (array_key_exists(3, $user->roles)) {
    if (strlen($emails) > 0) {
      $emails .= ' ' . $user->mail;
    } else {
      $emails = $user->mail;
    }
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: While the accepted answer by Eaton generally seems to be the case about Drupal, `entity_load('user')` actually does load all site users as objects, in an array indexed by uid.

Comment: This works but is extremely inefficient and would be a terrible idea on sites that have thousands of users.

Answer (score 2):

The SQL that worked for me:

```
$users = "";
$result = db_query('SELECT users.name AS users_name FROM users users
      INNER JOIN users_roles users_roles ON users.uid = users_roles.uid
      WHERE users_roles.rid = 4');

while ($existing_user = db_fetch_object($result)) {
      if ($users != "") $users .= ", ";
      $users .= $existing_user->users_name; // or do whatever
}
echo $users;
```

Keep in mind this is for Drupal 6 and I'm not sure about the performance of this for large user bases. Not sure about Drupal 7.

Comment: The performance would be fine. Your example in D7 code:

`var_dump(db_query('SELECT name FROM {users} u INNER JOIN {users_roles} r ON u.uid = r.uid WHERE r.rid = 4')->fetchCol());`

Answer (score 1):

One easy option is to use Views to generate the SQL (appears below the view its self when you press the preview button) for you and then use the [Drupal SQL abstraction layer](http://api.drupal.org/api/group/database/6) to get the results you need if you need to get access to the raw data rather than display a View.

It'd look a bit like this:

```
$result = db_query('SELECT users.uid AS uid,
   users.mail AS users_mail,
   users.name AS users_name
 FROM users users');
while ($existing_user = db_fetch_object($result)) {
    print_r($existing_user); // or do whatever
  }
```

Just add more fields to the view to get the complete query.

Comment: The Views SQL is unnecessarily complex, try

'SELECT uid, mail, name FROM {users}'

Answer (score 1):

In Drupal 8:

```
$users = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::loadMultiple();
```

And if you want to get e.g. only admins:

```
$admins = [];
foreach ($users as $user) {
  if ($user->hasRole('administrator')) {
    $admins[] = $user;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about any API can help to collect users by role. Here you are some link you can get something: http://drupal.org/node/82002.
Although SO is an awesome service I suggest using drupal.org or #drupal channel on irc.freenode.org for Drupal related questions.

Ps.: sometimes SQL is not that evil:)

Comment: I agree. I see a lot of Wordpress plugins who directly query the database instead of using predefined functions.

Comment: Just commenting to add that StackOverflow is great for Drupal questions and more people should ask them here.

Comment: sql queries should be avoided, since drupal7 will use new db api in order to abstract SQL (so you can use things like mongodb:)

Answer (score 0):

In Drupal 7, use EntityFieldQuery is the proper way.

Comment: could you provide an example on how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

In Drupal 8 the following works (in this example, load all users with the `administrator` role)

```
\Drupal::service('entity_type.manager')
  ->getStorage('user')
  ->loadByProperties(['roles' => 'administrator']);
```

will return a list of user entities.

To get a list of `uid`s instead, an entity field query:

```
$query = \Drupal::service('entity_type.manager')->getStorage('user')->getQuery();
$query->condition('roles', 'administrator');
$query->execute();
```