# getting list of users in Drupal 7 using PHP

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

How can I fetch user names from a Drupal 7 database using PHP?

See this:
[Is it possible to use the Drupal api to get a list of users?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1183158/is-it-possible-to-use-the-drupal-api-to-get-a-list-of-users)

This is for Drupal 6 and I have tried this but it says

```
Call to undefined function db_fetch_object()
```

Here is my code:

```
$result = db_query("SELECT name AS users_name FROM {users}");
while($row = db_fetch_object($result)) {    
        print_r($row);      
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Lets give it a try

```
$query = db_select('users', 'u');
    $query->fields('u', array('name'));
    $result = $query->execute();
    while($record = $result->fetchAssoc()) {
         print_r($record['name']);
    }
```

Comment: -1 dont use database queries if there is a drupal function for that. http://stackoverflow.com/a/6766138/1260906 or http://stackoverflow.com/a/17282755/1260906 or http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/46437/13526

Answer (score 5):

In Drupal 7 you can fetch all the users using entity_load,

To get the user names alone use the following,

```
$users = entity_load('user');
$user_names = array();
foreach ($users as $user_id => $user) {
  $user_names[] = $user->name;
}
```

Comment: Actually this function creates an issue, it changes current user session. Loads another user session automatically.

Answer (score 4):

[user_load_multiple](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--user--user.module/function/user_load_multiple/7)
Example from modules\profile\profile.pages.inc :

```
$users = user_load_multiple($uids);

$content = '';
foreach ($users as $account) {
  $profile = _profile_update_user_fields($fields, $account);
  $content .= theme('profile_listing', array('account' => $account, 'fields' => $profile));
}
```

*Note that in drupal 7 all things happen via entity. It's not so fast, but flexible...*

Answer (score 2):

```
$query = db_select('users', 'u');

$query
  ->condition('u.uid', 0, '<>')
  ->fields('u', array('name'));

$result = $query->execute();
```

[Here](http://drupal.org/node/310075)'s the whole documentation for Drupal 7 Database api

Answer (score 1):

Your code was almost correct if you had changed your while statement to read

```
while ($result as $row)
```

db_fetch_object is no longer needed in d7

it would have worked.  Although db_select calls specified in this post will work, they require more overhead and should be avoided unless you are trying to generate dynamic queries. Also see: http://drupal.org/node/224333 for info on how the apis have chaned between d6 and d7.  A search for db_fetch_object on this page would've given this info.

Answer (score 1):

My example code to get the list of users from drupal site,

```
$all_users = entity_load('user');
foreach($all_users as $value) {
  $user_list = (array)$value;
  $users[$user_list['uid']] = $user_list['name'];
}
```

Now you can get the answer from the array variable $users.

For example if you want to list all the user other than administrator (default user) means use the below example:

```
$all_users = entity_load('user');
foreach($all_users as $value) {
  $user_list = (array)$value;
  if($user_list['uid'] > 1) {
    $users[$user_list['uid']] = $user_list['name'];
  }
}
```

In the above both example, **the id of each user is placed as array index and the name of each usder is saved as array value.**

Answer (score 1):

Drupal 7 introduces a new concept of Entity.
User also included in Entity now.
You can use following function entity_load() to get the details of all entities.

To fetch the usernames in array :

```
$users = entity_load('user');
$usernames = array();
foreach($users as $id => $user){
    $usernames[$user->uid] = $user->name;
}
print_r($usernames);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A Better way

```
function GetAllActiveUsers() {
  $query = new EntityFieldQuery();
  $query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'user')
        ->propertyCondition('status', 1);
  $results = $query->execute();
  $uids = array_keys($results['user']);
  return $uids;
}
```

This will return all active users and use the code in a function to use it as a helper

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$query = db_select('users', 'u')
->fields('u')
->execute();
while($result = $query->fetchAssoc()) {
     print_r($record['name']);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this as well,

```
$query = db_select('users', 'u');
    $query->fields('u', array('uid, name'));
    $result = $query->execute();
    while($record = $result->fetchAssoc()) {
         $account = user_load($record['uid']);
         if($account->uid){
             print $account->name;
         }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Simplified example with [fetchAll()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/DatabaseStatementEmpty%3a%3afetchAll/7):

```
 $users = db_select('users', 'u')
    ->fields('u', array('uid'))
    ->execute()
    ->fetchAll();

 foreach ($users as $user) {
    $full_user = user_load($user->uid);
    //do your stuff here 
 }
```